# MVC5 Facebook Authentication not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook, oauth-2.0

I have followed [this tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/security/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-app-with-facebook-and-google-oauth2-and-openid-sign-on) on how to enable Facebook login on my MVC 5 application, but people are getting the following error:

[image: facebook error]

I have an SSL certification installed on my server, and have that installed on the web application (through IIS).

On Facebook's Developer page I have this:

[image: facebook developer]

Why isn't this working?

Comment: By the looks of it, this error only occurs when your site is accessed via `https://bejebeje.com/`, and not when accessed via `https://www.bejebeje.com/`. Simply remove the `www.` part in Site URL setting.

Comment: If I do that, would it make it work for both versions?

Comment: I had the same issue, I deleted my facebook application and created it again. I don't know why but it works... haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the latest version of MVC you need to add the "/signin-facebook" to the end of your application URL. The facebook instruction page here http://www.oauthforaspnet.com/providers/facebook/ shows how to change that default suffix by using

```
var options = new FacebookAuthenticationOptions
{
    AppId = "Your App ID",
    AppSecret = "Your App Secret",
    CallbackPath = new PathString("/oauth-redirect/facebook")
};
app.UseFacebookAuthentication(options);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Facebook App, Go to settings and then Advanced tab. At the bottom "Embedded browser OAuth Login" enable this option. This worked for me.

Comment: @Parshant I did that and also did what CBroe suggested, but still getting the error!